# How do I model a conditional logistic model with varying choice set in R

Tags: r, mlogit, clogit

I have a dataset, where individuals ( no repetition of individuals in the data) face different choice sets. I wanted to model the individuals choice using the mlogit function in R. All the examples on mlogit show that the individuals face the same alternatives (or same number of alternatives). But, as in my question each individual face different alternatives (and different number of alternatives), can I still use mlogit. How can I make use of the 'chid.var' option of mlogit for this?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: `mlogit` will infer the choice set based on data appearing in the rows of your dataset. Set `chid.var` and you should be good to go. See [this document](http://facweb.knowlton.ohio-state.edu/pviton/courses2/crp5700/5700-mlogit.pdf) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Please don't give duplicate answers.  Either you have not sufficiently tailored your answers to the specifics of the question or the questions are so nearly identical that one should be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I face the same situation as yours. I am estimating a discrete choice model in which individuals choose products he wants. Each individual faces a same number choice sets, while the choice sets may be different among individuals. For example, individual A may face 4 choice sets: A1, B1,C1,D1,and individual B may face another 4 choice sets: A2, B2, C2, D2 (each choice set(A1，A2，...D2...) has three altnatives:product a, product b and an "do not choose" option). When the data collection was finished, how to deal with the dataset to conduct a mixed logit using mlogit pack

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you absolutely must use mlogit or R, but I released a package called pylogit that estimates conditional logistic models and can handle differing choice sets. See examples here: https://github.com/timothyb0912/pylogit/tree/master/examples. If you want to use the package, it can be installed via pip or gotten through github or PyPI.

Comment: I used mlogit in R and starting to understand pylogit. I am unsure how the model specification works with varying choice sets.  In my case, an individual can face any where from 20 to 100 different alternatives for a choice situation and other individuals may have the same 20 or completely different 40 choices. Can you please advise me on how to use the pylogit and model specification if I have varying choice sets ranging from 20 to 100 choices, different choices in each user's case

Comment: The number of and varying composition of choice sets shouldn't matter. Simply have 1 row per available alternative for each decision maker.

As a practical matter, one will have to ensure that the specification one uses does not make of "alternative specific" coefficients since there is no real notion of a consistent alternative anymore (i.e. alternative 1 for person 1 doesn't equal alternative 1 for person 2).

Comment: thanks. yes, my data is in long format, one row per user per alt. 
so if I have 20 alternatives for 1 choice set , completely different 100 for 2 set, and 40 overlapping and different other alternatives for 3 choice set, should I specify the model specification as below ?
basic_specification["distance"] = [np.arange(101)].    

also, can I specify both alternative specific variables (say distance which is applicable to all alternatives and varies by alt.) and decision maker specific variables (user age) in this fashion or should there be any difference between the two.